# Executing binary: `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found

Tags: unix, gcc, opencv, glibc

I'm trying to run some pre-compiled code but I'm getting the following error:

```
./bin/stipdet: /cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.3.4/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./bin/stipdet)
```

I googled the error and saw that some people solved similar problems by deleting the `libstdc++.so.6` and adding a new dynamic link pointing to `usr/local/lib`. But I don't have root access on the system I'm trying to run this on, so I can't add/delete files in that directory.

Does anyone know another way to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**:
I tried adding the directory of another version of `libstdc++.so.6` to the `LD_PRELOAD`, but it didn't work for me, it still uses the file from the wrong directory.

The same happens when I prepend the correct directory to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Finally, I also tried to remove everything else from the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then add the correct directory (just to try). This seemed to fix the original error!
But now I'm getting the same error at a different location:

```
./bin/stipdet: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /var/scratch/user/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.2)
```

Apparently `opencv` uses a different `glibcxx` version, so switching to another `libstdc` breaks `opencv`. Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you've got the correct version of libstdc++.so.6 installed elsewhere (e.g. in your home directory), you can either set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or use LD_PRELOAD, see
[What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with the results of your advice. It now breaks somewhere else :(

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you tell what OS you are running. If it is Solaris, you might want to try setting LD_NOVERSION to tell the runtime linker to ignore the shared library versions.

`export LD_NOVERSION=1`

Comment: when I type uname -a it says Linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. And when I log in to the system it says "Based on CentOS 5"

Comment: I'm afraid there is no LD_NOVERSION equivalent with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The libstdc++ FAQ answers your original question: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

For the update, that shouldn't happen. The newer `libstdc++.so` thaqt should be found in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` provides all the symbols of the older one. Maybe `/var/scratch/user/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.2` was linked to an absolute path, not to the SONAME `libstdc++.so.6`, you could check that by running:

```
ldd /var/scratch/user/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the file A(/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6) to the dictionary B(/opt/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v711/sys/os/glnxa64) and it worked.